# Custom tab is unclickable

Tags: unity-game-engine, customization

I have some Unity .asset files which contains 3D models. I want to be able to convert / export these 3D models into a more common format which will be accepted by 3D Max.

I read that I need to use a custom script since Unity doesn't support this out of the box, so I tried to set up this plugin script:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjExporter

I created a new project called Test, copied the two CS scripts into the "My Project Name/Editor" folder, and although the custom tab in Unity shows up, it is not click-able.

Also, I had to change line 79 to:

```
objMaterial.textureName = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(mats[material].mainTexture);
```

From:

```
objMaterial.textureName = EditorUtility.GetAssetPath(mats[material].mainTexture);
```

As it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Unity?  In 3.5.7 you should see the following:

[image]

The `Custom` menu item should be in the main tool bar.  Also included for reference is the project hierarchy, to show that the scripts are in the correct folder.  I copied the scripts verbatim from the OP's link.

Comment: I'm using Unity 4.1.2f1 free edition. My screen looks like this (I have tried Editor and editor as the directory name): http://s16.postimg.org/53z35qu83/Screenshot.png

Comment: Tested in 4.1.0, no issues.  Your image shows a compiler problem and your assets folder has a strange amount of extraneous files.

Comment: The extraneous files are the .asset files which contain the 3D models which I want to export. I don't need to be able to compile, all I want to be able to do is export the 3D models in the .asset files.

Comment: If the compiler error is related to the obj export script then you do need to compile.  Editor scripts need compilation love just like everything else.

Comment: This is just a guess but I would try removing all those .asset files first, leaving just the editor scripts.  See what happens.  Someone can correct me if I'm wrong but I don't recall there being a way to read asset files like you are trying to do.  You need to import them from a package.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I created a new project, added the two CS files to "Test/Editor" folder and now the Custom tab shows up! However when I click it, nothing is happening. I updated my original post with a screenshot too.